# Custom UITableViewCells repeating when navigating to viewcontroller

Tags: swift, uitableview, xcode7

I am making a running app, and would like the user to see the races/marathons in their city. When clicking on the cell the user is navigated to a new view controller with details of the marathon. But upon pressing the back button to go back to the table the cells repeat. for example, if scrolling on the table it will display cell 1, cell 2,cell 3, cell 4,cell 1, cell 2,cell 3, cell 4 and will repeat more every time I navigate to the view controller with the table. 
The code for the table is:

```
//MARK: TableView
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return exhibitions.count
}
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let singleCell: marathonTableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("marathonCell") as! marathonTableViewCell


    singleCell.marathonName.text = exhibitions[indexPath.row]
    singleCell.entryNumber.text = "\(entryNumber[indexPath.row])"
    singleCell.entries.text = "\(entires[indexPath.row])"




    return singleCell


}



func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {



    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("marathonDetail", sender: self)


}

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if(segue.identifier == "marathonCardDetail"){

        var upcoming: marathonDetailViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! marathonDetailViewController

        let indexPath = self.marathonsTableView.indexPathForSelectedRow!



        let currentCell = marathonsTableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! marathonTableViewCell

        let marathonEvents = currentCell.marathonName.text


        upcoming.nameMarathon = marathonEvents

        self.marathonsTableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)




    }
}
```

I am using swift, Xcode 7, and Parse as my backend.

Answer (score 0):

I think u have to init ur array before update tableview.

When u click back button, tableview may refresh.

So make some code that makes ur array new, and then call tableview.reloadData()

Comment: what do you mean by "init"